# pageContext remains undefined in Gatsby JS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-i18next

I'm following this tutorial for creating a multi language site based on Gatsby JS:

https://itnext.io/techniques-approaches-for-multi-language-gatsby-apps-8ba13ff433c5

I'm creating a ContextProvider as follows:

*.pageContext.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const PageContext = React.createContext({});

export const PageContextProvider = ({ children, pageContext }) => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  i18n.changeLanguage(pageContext.lang);

  return <PageContext.Provider value={pageContext}>{children}</PageContext.Provider>;
};

export const usePageContext = () => React.useContext(PageContext);
```

and this is my gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const _ = require('lodash')
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')
const config = require('./gatsby-config')

exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions: { createPage, deletePage } }) => {

  await deletePage(page);

  await Promise.all(
    config.siteMetadata.supportedLanguages.map(async lang => {
      
      const originalPath = page.path;
      const localizedPath = `/${lang}${page.path}`

      await createPage({
        ...page,
        path: localizedPath,
        context: {
          ...page.context,
          originalPath,
          lang,
        },
      });
    })
  );
};
```

this is gatsby-ssr.js

```
import React from 'react';
import i18n from './src/i18n';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { PageContextProvider } from './src/pageContext';

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>{element}</I18nextProvider>;
};

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <PageContextProvider value={props.pageContext}>{element}</PageContextProvider>;
};
```

and this is my gatsby-browser.js

```
export { wrapPageElement, wrapRootElement } from './gatsby-ssr';
```

The pages are getting created, but when I try to access them from the browser, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined

and it refers to line 8 of pageContext.js

So basically the pageContext remains undefined even though the onCreatePage does seem to work correctly.

I've been working to fix this all day, still no idea.
In case you can see help, thanks a lot.

Comment: where are you using the `PageContextProvider` ?

Comment: In my gatsby-ssr.js and gatsby-browser.js. I'm updating my question to include those, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the error was in the wrapPageElement inside gatsby-ssr.js
Here below the correct one:

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <PageContextProvider pageContext={props.pageContext}>{element}</PageContextProvider>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This defines a `PageContextProvider` component that accepts `children` and a `pageContext` prop:

```
const PageContextProvider = ({ children, pageContext })
```

When you use it, you would pass these props like this:

```
<PageContextProvider pageContext="some value">Children here</PageContextProvider>
```

You are using it like this, though:

```
<PageContextProvider value={props.pageContext}>{element}</PageContextProvider>
```

This is passing a `value` prop that does not get used. You probably want to instead update the definition of `PageContextProvider` to accept a `value` prop:

```
export const PageContextProvider = (props) => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  i18n.changeLanguage(props.value.lang);

  return <PageContext.Provider {...props} />;
};
```

This will pass through all props to the actual `PageContext.Provider` while still tapping into them to call your `i18n.changeLanguage` function as previously.

Comment: @coreward thanks for your help, however it still doesn't function as it should. I'll keep working!